# Flutter The const variable 'IconData' must be initialized

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use `Flutter Icons` on our project and after downloading font and dart class i put them into project, but for dart class i get this error

```
The const variable 'IconData' must be initialized
```

`MyFlutterApp` class:

```
class MyFlutterApp {
  MyFlutterApp._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'MyFlutterApp';

  static const IconData 3d_rotation = const IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData ac_unit = const IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData access_alarm = const IconData(0xe802, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
}
```

how can i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Variable names may not start with a digit. Change it to:

```
  static const IconData three_d_rotation = const IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
```